# How to send both video and data to Node sever using multipart/form-data and express-fileupload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am attempting to upload a video to a node server as well as some data that describes the video in the same request. I have an HTML (pug/jade) form imput that accepts everything in one form, with a post method that sends this to my server. I am using express-fileupload as the middleware.

Form:

```
form(method='POST', action='/clips/create', enctype="multipart/form-data")
    .form-group
        label(for='video_upload') Upload Video
        input#video_upload.form-control(type='file', accept='video/*', placeholder='Enter Video', name="video")
        br
        hr
        br
        video#original(controls='', autoplay='', preload='metadata', width="820" height="540" )
        hr
        nav
            #slider-range
        input(type='hidden', id='clip_start', value='4')
        input(type='hidden', id='clip_end', value='10')
    p
        label(for='amount') Clip Range (in seconds):
        input#amount(type='text', readonly='', style='border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;')
    hr
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
```

I am able to revieve the video perfectly fine, but I do not know how to access the other form data such as the hidden input of 'clip_start'. The server-side code:

```
router.post("/create", function (req, res) {
  let video = req.files.video;
  let time = req.body.clip_start //this is undefined
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `req.body.clip_start`? https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body

Comment: Yes it's undefined, sadly.

Comment: Which middleware are you using? Have you tried multer yet?

Comment: Sorry I somehow completely forgot to mention the middleware, its express-fileupload. I havn't attempted to use multer yet, but will try if Im unsuccessfull with this.